# Searching a string within a column range. If true takes a value within the same row and adds it

Tags: excel, logic

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43q58.jpg)

Hello, I apologize if this has been answered a million times before, but I cannot seem to form the correct question into google to find what I need. I'm sure it is real basic and easy, but I have very little experience with Excel.

My problem is that I want to sum up the numbers in column B if the string matches in column A. In the image provided I manually summed them up separately but I need something that will search all of column A and add up the number in column B in the same row if the name matches.

I appreciate any help and say thank you in advance!

I've tried something silly like this:
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Yellow", A;A)), SUM(B:B),0)

As you can imagine it only summed up all of column B instead of the value in each row that matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum only exact matches, use SUMIF / SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"YELLOW",$B$1:$B$6)
```

If you want to sum anything that contains your string, use wildcards:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"*YELLOW*",$B$1:$B$6)
```

You can also reference a cell instead of typing your search string in the formula:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$6,"*"&D1&"*",$B$1:$B$6)
```